# Remove a text link from page by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have in my html page: `<a href="link">some text</a>`

How can I do it in JavaScript to find the value of A tag as "some text" and remove all the a tag and the a value ?

I want to remove `<a href="link">some text</a>` only if there is a value = some text

thanks!

Comment: Will you be eager to use jQuery?

Comment: I try via jQuery but I dont know from where to start :\

Answer (score 4):

Vanilla JavaScript

```
function removeAllByTextContent(tag, search) {
  var anchors  = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);

  for (var i=anchors.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    var    a = anchors[i], 
        text = a.textContent || a.innerText;

    if (text == search) a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
  }
}
```

call as:

```
removeAllByTextContent("a", "some text");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    if(a[i].innerText == 'some text' || a[i].textContent == 'some text'){
        a[i].parentNode.removeChild(a[i]);      
    }
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/U8cZZ/1/

Comment: `innerText` not supported by some browsers, for example FF

Answer (score 0):

You can use the text() css selector with a framework like mootools: http://jsfiddle.net/9YPYc/

Answer (score 0):

if you use jquery:

```
$('a').each(function(){if($(this).text()=="some text")$(this).remove()});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are eager to use jQuery (as said in the comment) then load jQuery file first

```
<script type="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And type following code withing your `script` tag

```
$(function(){
 $('a').filter(function(){
     if($(this).html()=='some text') return true;
 }).remove();
})
```

See a working a **demo here** http://jsfiddle.net/MbJVf/1/

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery:

```
$('a[href=link]').remove();
```